# No auth header sent by swagger UI using Swashbuckle with OAuth code flow in .NET 6

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swashbuckle

I am trying to get OAuth code flow with PCKE to work with Swashbuckle (6.2.3) and swagger ui in .NET 6. There are a few things that happen **successfully**:

- In swagger UI I can click on "Authorize" button and get redirected to Azure for login.
- The redirect successfully returns to swagger ui and I can see in the network tab that the token is retrieved from Azure by swagger ui.

The problem is when I try to call the sample weather forecast API using swagger UI, no token is attached to the authorization header and it looks like this in the request:

```
authorization: Bearer undefined
```

And here is my code:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    
    const string oAuth2 = "oauth2";
    options.AddSecurityDefinition(oAuth2, new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
        {
            AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["AzureAdB2C:AuthorizationUrl"]),
                TokenUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["AzureAdB2C:TokenUrl"]),
                Scopes = {{"openid", "Sign users in"}, {"offline_access", "Maintain access to data you have given it access to"}}
            }
        },
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "bearer",
        Name = "authorization"
    });
    
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Id = oAuth2,
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                },
            }, new List<string> {"openid", "offline_access"}
        }
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.OAuthClientId(builder.Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"]);
        options.OAuthScopes("openid", "offline_access");
        options.OAuthUsePkce();
    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any ideas?

UPDATE:
I have been able to get it to work with something like this:

```cs
        options.UseRequestInterceptor("(req) => { req.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + window?.swaggerUIRedirectOauth2?.auth?.token?.id_token; return req; }");
```

But it doesn't look like a proper solution.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a proper solution for this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I too seem to be running into this same issue and am also wondering if you ever found a proper solution? @mohammad-alinia

Comment: I'm going to give your question an up tick for the UPDATE you made with the solution, given there is no answer to up tick.

Comment: @Morph, that's not the way to do it as it adds the token to request headers for all endpoints, whether secured or not. check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify in the OpenApiSecurityScheme to use the id_token instead the access_token that is the default by adding it to the Extensions:

```
Extensions =
{
  // Setting x-tokenName to id_token will send response_type=token id_token and the nonce to the auth provider.
  // x-tokenName also specifieds the name of the value from the response of the auth provider to use as bearer token.
  { "x-tokenName", new OpenApiString("id_token") }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/inouiw/SwaggerUIJsonWebToken/blob/master/Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the `SecurityDefinition` and `SecurityRequirement` but missed the part that specifies which endpoints need authorization. The token is attached only to requests called to secured endpoints.

You'll need to add

```
options.OperationFilter<MyOperationFilter>();
```

to your `AddSwaggerGen(` configuration, with the filter as something like this:

```
public class MyOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any())
        {
            operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
            {
                //same security requirment defined in AddSecurityRequirement
                new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Id = oAuth2,
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                            },
                        }, new List<string> {"openid", "offline_access"}
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```